# Correct way to pass interfaces to methods

Tags: go, interface

Preference: I'm new to Golang and keen to improve.

So I'm trying to learn from Dave Cheney's talk here: https://youtu.be/NwEuRO_w8HE?t=812 where we pass interfaces to methods to make code clearer and more generic.

I've implemented an example below, where I have a struct that can be outputted either to the std.out or to a file. However, I feel like it's a bit redundant just making empty structs (called "print" and "save" in ,my example), just so I can attach methods. How can I improve this?

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
)

type file struct {
    data string
}

func (f *file) output(w io.Writer) error {
    len, err := w.Write([]byte(f.data))
    if err != nil {
        return err
    } else {
        log.Println("Bytes Out: ", len)
        return nil
    }
}

type print struct{}

func (print *print) Write(p []byte) (n int, err error) {
    return fmt.Printf("%s\n", p)
}

type save struct{}

func (s *save) Write(p []byte) (n int, err error) {
    err = ioutil.WriteFile("./dat1", []byte(p), 0644)
    if err != nil {
        return -1, err
    }
    return len(p), nil
}
func main() {
    f := file{"test"}
    s := save{}
    p := print{}

    f.output(&s)
    f.output(&p)
}
```

Comment: If you need a method set, then you need a type to declare methods. There’s nothing wrong with the empty structs if you need to have a method. You could use the function type itself, but it doesn’t save you anything here.

Comment: the whole print struct can be replaced with `os.Stdout`. For the rest, it is desirable. This helps you reduce coupling between two pieces of implementation.

Comment: "I feel like it's a bit redundant just making empty structs" Its not redundant, its basically just wrong. You got your abstraction the wrong way around. `file.output` is fine and a good use of an interface (here io.Writer). As neither `save` nor `print` have any kind of state: Make them a functions. There is absolutely no need to make them types implementing io.Writer. You solutions is neither flexible nor clear nor generic.

Comment: As Dave explained and you did: file.output takes an interface. You got that but save and print are pure noise. To print call file.output(os.Stdout), to save get yourself an os.File f and do file.output(f).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `print` or `save` types here. You have a method, `output`, that takes an `io.Writer`; the whole point of that is that you can pass it *any writer*. Both stdout and files are writers, so everything else here is unnecessary. You could just:

```
func main() {
    f := file{"test"}

    fp,err := os.Create("./dat1")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    f.output(fp)  // This writes to a file
    f.output(os.Stdout)  // This writes to stdout
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your intentions aren't clear, but to answer your original question: how to pass functions as interface values?

You could create a single adapter-like type that implements `io.Writer`, and when its `Write()` method is called, it forwards to a function of your choice. A typical example of this is the [`http.HandlerFunc`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#HandlerFunc): it's a function type that implements [`http.Handler`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Handler), so a function can be passed when an `http.Handler` implementation is required.

For an `io.Writer` adapter, it could look like this:

```
type WriteFunc func(p []byte) (n int, err error)

func (w WriteFunc) Write(p []byte) (n int, err error) {
    return w(p)
}
```

And if you have functions like these:

```
func PrintWrite(p []byte) (n int, err error) {
    return fmt.Printf("%s\n", p)
}

func SaveWrite(p []byte) (n int, err error) {
    err = ioutil.WriteFile("./dat1", []byte(p), 0644)
    if err != nil {
        return -1, err
    }
    return len(p), nil
}
```

You can use them as `io.Writer` like this:

```
f.output(WriteFunc(PrintWrite))
f.output(WriteFunc(SaveWrite))
```

Try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/GLmenjUHZs1).